# PHP Daylight savings bug?

Tags: php, date, datetime, dst

I just ran into a strange bug that has occurs in PHP running in Pacific Time (and probably others). I had code to get the first day of a week (sunday) given an arbitrary date (in UNIX timestamp) in that week:

```
$day = date('w', $date);
$start_of_week = date('Y-m-d', $date - ($day * 60*60*24));
echo $start_of_week;
```

Prints `2014-03-08`

This works for every single date that I've tried, except for those in the week of March 9th, 2014, which happens to be the week of daylight savings time in the US. For those, `$start_of_week` is '2014-03-08', which is a Saturday.

When I run this code with the timezone set to GMT, I get the correct output ('2014-03-09').

Additionally, when I change the code to the following in PST, I get the correct output:

```
$day = date('w', $date);
$start_of_week = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$day day", $date));
echo $start_of_week;
```

Prints `2014-03-09`

So...WTF? Why is there a difference between `strtotime("-1 day", $date)` and `$date - 60*60*24`? Seems like it's jumping between different timezones.

[codepad example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/SFu6DU)

Comment: Have a look at this comment in the manual: http://php.net/strtotime#41328

Comment: Good to know, but that doesn't explain why `-1 day` and `-60*60*24` yield different results, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, I think that if you put your numbers into a strtotime function like you do with `-1 day` then you'd end up with the same result, but my instinct tells me that this is happening because you're hard coding that time

Comment: When you use `-1 day`, it uses the time-of-day from `$date`, and just changes the date. When you use `- 60 * 60 * 24` it rolls the clock back 24 hours. On the day that DST changes, there are only 23 hours in the day, so it goes an hour too far.

Answer (score 0):

When you use -1 day, it uses the time-of-day from $date, and just changes the date. When you use - 60 * 60 * 24 it rolls the clock back 24 hours. On the day that DST changes, there are only 23 hours in the day, so it goes an hour too far.

– Barmar Mar 19 '14 at 22:11